# why conversion of double to string using NSDate adds extra 30 min

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
double duration = 20; // duration is in seconds 

NSDate* durationDate = [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:duration];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;


formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];

NSString *durationString=[formatter stringFromDate:durationDate];//here durationString should have 20
```

but i am getting 30:20? from where this 30 min is getting added. I have tried giving bigger numbers then also same result

please let me know thoughts on this and how to solve this

Comment: NSDateFormatter isn't really intended to format raw time values.  It's trying to format it as a timestamp, and you live in India which is in a timezone that's on a half-hour boundary.

Comment: It sounds like you're on India Standard Time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably on India Standard Time?

The reference date is defined to be at midnight GMT. IST is GMT+5:30.

So when you add 20 seconds to the reference date you get 20 seconds past midnight in GMT. When you then create a date formatter and don't set anything else to it, it'll operate in your device's natural time zone. That means that when you ask it for the minutes and seconds at the end of the time you get 30 minutes and 20 seconds.

`NSDate`s are an absolute time, abstract of any time zone or calendar. If five devices in five separate time zones all call `[NSDate date]` simultaneously to get the current time, they'd all get objects with the same value.

`NSDateFormatter` combines an `NSDate` with an `NSCalendar` and an `NSTimeZone` to determine minutes, seconds, hours, months, years, etc.

Comment: How i Can solve this problem, should i need to try some other mechanism to convert seconds to string???

Comment: If you just want to print the number and you don't care about it being seconds, use a standard `NSString` `+stringWithFormat:` format code or an `NSNumberFormatter`. If you really definitely want to use the `NSDateFormatter` then maybe explicitly set the timezone on your date formatter to GMT?